# Sharepoint Calendar customisation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to customize the SharePoint calendar in a way, I want to deny the user from adding meetings on specific day and specific hours when clicking on add. how can I achieve that out of the box , if not how can that be done in a custom way .

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOB way to do this.
Two options:

Option 1:

create an event handler (itemAdding) and check if your validation logic is met, otherwise cancel the insertion.

Option 2:

Leverage the javascript `PreSaveItem` function. Something like (requires jQuery):

```
function PreSaveItem(){
    var $start = $('[title="Start Time"]');
    var $end = $('[title="End Time"]');

    var starDate = $start.val();
    var startHour = $start.parents('tr:first').find('select:first').val();
    var startMinutes = $start.parents('tr:first').find('select:last').val();

    var endDate = $end.val();
    var endHour = $end.parents('tr:first').find('select:first').val();
    var endMinutes = $end.parents('tr:first').find('select:last').val();

    //your validation logic here

    if (!validationPassed){
        alert('You cannot add events on this time frame');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When working with dates in javascript, I always recommend using the excellent [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Yes, you can try the Option 2 - PreSave